# static_cast can not be down casted when derived class is virtually inherited

Tags: c++, inheritance

I seem to have a decent understanding of c++ castings. How static_cast/dynamic_cast work. One concept which I am finding little hard to digest is that:

What is the technical reason for C++ not to allow the down casting using static_cast if derived class is virtually inherited. Say for example :

```
class B {
}

class D : public B {
}

int main() {
  B* b = new B;
  D* d = new D;
  b = static_cast<B*> d; // Valid
  d = static_cast<D*> b; // Valid

  b = d; // Valid. Implicit casting.
}
```

But when class 'D' is virtually inherited,

```
 class D : virtual public B {
 }
```

then below line breaks,

```
 d = static_cast<D*> b; // Invalid
```

Although I have read couple of related posts to it but nothing seems to be the clear answer.

Comment: Do you get an error or a warning?

Comment: @MikeMB. Error. Interested in error message?

Comment: Btw.: Dereferencind `d` in the first example would yield undefined behavior.

Comment: @mpiatek, Yes. It might be. But answer written there is not clear enough to be understood.

Comment: @MikeMB, Agreed.

Comment: Well, it *is* an exact duplicate, if it's not clear enough you should probably ask for clarifications there instead of re-asking the exact same question.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, I understand.

Comment: In short: In case of virtual inheritance, the offset between B and D depends on the runtime type of whatever `b` points to. As static_cast needs to know this offset at compile time it can't be used.

Comment: By the way, I feel that the best answer in there is the second one by James Kanze; basically, there's no strict technical reason, more like a feeling that `static_cast` should be static and not require any dynamic type (=vtable) lookup, but casting when `virtual` inheritance is involved cannot be reliably done without it.